# Who gave Sauron his name?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, names, sauron

Sauron, of course, wasn't Sauron's original name. He was called *Mairon the Admirable*. Mairon was only given the name Sauron upon his defection to evil. The name Sauron was given in mockery of his previous name.

> saura (Þ) adj. foul, evil-smelling,
>   putrid
>
> Sauro (Þ) masc. name Sauron
>   (Þ), the Abhorred, name of a
>   Maia, the second Dark Lord
>
> <sub><sup>Quenya-English Dictionary</sup></sub>

Melkor, his master, was named Morgoth *specifically by Fëanor*. **Who, exactly, renamed Mairon as Sauron (the Abhorred)?**

Comment: I'm curious about this Quenya-English Dictionary from which you cite.

Comment: Didn't JRR give Sauron his name?

Comment: @AntonSherwood  http://folk.uib.no/hnohf/quen-eng.doc

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### The Eldar renamed him Sauron

> Among those of his servants that have names the greatest was that spirit whom the Eldar called Sauron, or Gorthaur the Cruel.
> <sub>The Silmarillion: Valaquenta</sub>

The *Complete Tolkien Companion* By JEA Tyler (although not canon is very well sourced) suggests the following

> Sauron is a later name given to him by the High-elves in their own language, and means ‘the Abhorred’, while the Grey-elves knew him as Gorthaur ‘the Cruel’.
> <sub>The Complete Tolkien Guide</sub>

This supports the above that he was renamed by the Elves of Valinor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58844/discussion-between-edlothiad-and-disturbedneo).

Comment: Perhaps it is worth noting whether "Sauron" is the actual word used by the Eldar, or this is Tolkien's "translation" into English (cf. Maura -> Frodo). Then again IIRC Tolkien only "translated" Westron words, so then it has got to be the former.

Comment: @void_ptr It's the actual Quenya word.

Comment: @Voronwë There's not always a Jon Oliver who's responsible for a common name. Sometimes it just comes out of the Zeitgeist. There wasn't one historian who announced Constantine I was 'the Great' and everyone else copied them: there was a consensus about how the clerics felt about the guy and a common word that fit the bill.